# Navision 2017 Adding Assembly BOM Item says it already exists

Tags: c#, soap-client, navision

I am working on Navision 2017 and using its SOAP Service, I am trying to add a BOM component.
I use the CreateMultiple method, but I always get this error:

The BOM Component already exists. Identification fields and values: Parent Item No.='100092448',Line No.='20000''

The item '100092448' is new and shouldn't have any BOM components associated.

I have been at this for a week now.

I tried searching online for a solution to no avail.
I tried moving the method to single creates, and still errors.
I tried a create then update method, gets another error.

Comment: Such error should be debugable via Nav debugger. Have you tried it?